# iOS - How to create configuration for Appstore and Ad-hoc release

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, xcodebuild

I want to build an Xcode project on command line. So I am using `xcodebuild` for cleaning, building and exporting. I want to export as `Appstore IPA` and also `Ad-Hoc IPA (iTunes)`. Can I distinguish adhoc & appsore from export parameters? Or, should I create separate configurations? If I need to create separate configuration for different type release, which key/value should differ.

I am using a hybrid project which is created as objective C, but also using swift 3 codes. If I have any misconception, please let clarify it.

Advance thanks

Comment: How are you distributing your ad hoc? If you're using TestFlight, you don't need to create separate IPA files.

Comment: No I have tester team in my company, who need to check with iTunes ipa. Is not it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't mean it wasn't possible, just that it's easier with TestFlight. I think you can actually build just the ad hoc one and when you upload it, you can re-sign it for the store, but I haven't tried that in a while. If you want to build both, you'll want to create separate configurations. The only difference will be the signing settings.